# The listener supports no services - connection closed

Tags: oracle, listener, tnsnames

Trying to configure a dblink I damaged the oracle listener in a SUSE with db Oracle, I undone the changes made in the files listener.ora and tnsnames.ora but it did not work, then I rebooted the computer and used lsnrctl status

```
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST = 192.168.3.250) (PORT = 1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS: no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS: protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   Linux Error: 111: Connection refused
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC) (KEY = EXTPROC1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS: no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS: protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   Linux Error: 111: Connection refused
```

I understand that if I left everything as it was, LISTENER should have started automatically and without problems.

Now I used $ ORACLE_HOME / bin / lsnrctl start LISTENER

```
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias ​​LISTENER
Version TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date 07-JAN-2019 20:35:42
Uptime 0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 0 sec
Trace Level off
Security ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP OFF
Listener Parameter File /opt/oracle/product/11gR2/db/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File /opt/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/srvbdlnx/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary ...
  (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = tcp) (HOST = 192.168.3.250) (PORT = 1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = ipc) (KEY = EXTPROC1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully
```

Then I restarted LISTENER and apparently is listening:

```
Listening Endpoints Summary ...
  (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = tcp) (HOST = 192.168.3.250) (PORT = 1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = ipc) (KEY = EXTPROC1521)))
Services Summary ...
Service "app" has 1 instance (s).
  Instance "app", status READY, has 1 handler (s) for this service ...
Service "appXDB" has 1 instance (s).
  Instance "app", status READY, has 1 handler (s) for this service ...
The command completed successfully
```

But when I try to log in remotely in the application it does not work:

```
ORA-12537:TNS:connection closed
```

Modify the local_listener parameter in the db but it did not work.

```
alter system set local_listener='(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.3.250)(PORT=1521))';
```

The database is running because I can log in with the SYSTEM user in sqlplus in console.

my listener.ora file:

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST = 192.168.3.250) (PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC) (KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = /opt/oracle
```

tnsnames.ora

```
APP =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST = 192.168.3.250) (PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = app)
    )
  )
```

Is there something missing in the files that I modified? 
What changes could have occurred due to the modifications I made to those files?
What other commands can I use to see more errors?

I am new, thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to open the file `listener.ora` in the editor vi and remove the extra characters at the end of the line, if you copied the lines from windows, that is the reason. If this does not help, re-create the file `listener.ora` using the utility Oracle Net Configuration Assistant.

Comment: Thanks for answering, for some reason, when I modified these files, they changed the permissions of the /var/tmp/.oracle directory, this was discovered because the Oracle service could not stop the service.

# chown -R oracle:oinstall .oracle
# chmod -R 01777 .oracle

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, when I modified these files, they changed the permissions of the /var/tmp/.oracle directory, this was discovered because the user Oracle user could not stop the listener.

```
# chown -R oracle:oinstall .oracle
# chmod -R 01777 .oracle
```